# Android Google Map v2 - Starting activity when clicking on marker infoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have seen that people are finding a lot of difficulties with this specific task and I am in need of help as well.

I have successfully created Markers on a Map using the default code that Google has provided. But now I want to be able to click on "InfoWindow" to open a new activity so I can add more information.

- **From this basic marker with Title and Snippet:**

  http://mobisys.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Screenshot_2013-04-04-17-19-581.png
- **Then to click on it and open a blank activity:**

  http://tuts-authors.s3.amazonaws.com/mobile.tutsplus.com/Shane%20Conder%20and%20Lauren%20Darcey/2012/09/25/Android-Creating-Hello-Worlds_Emulator-basic-hello-world.png

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

If you can answer this ***please put up some code or an example.*** 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: do you know of an example Raghunandan? where I can see some code? Thanks

Comment: http://www.verious.com/article/detect-info-window-click-implements-on-info-window-click-listener/. Example. displays a toast on info window click do what you want on click of info window by modifying the same

Comment: So this just creates a toast? not a new blank page

Comment: you can do what you need instead of toast displaying. left to you to decide what you want to do

Answer (score 55, accepted):

add this to your code

```
 Mymap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I will post some example code for other users!

Comment: what is Mymap? Mine cannot resolve symbol 'setOnInfoWindowClickListener' because Mymap is not correct for my code... Is it the instance of the GoogleMap class? Is it the Class for the Activity? Or is it a new separate class inheriting from GoogleMap class?

Comment: @AlexVPerl Hi it maybe odd, but I use the title with a json string. Then you need to use a custom infowindow adapter to correctly display your content. Something like {"title":"Your Title","param1":"yourParam}.

Answer (score 1):

```
This method works even well with multiple markers. get the title of the marker using marker.getTitle() and Starts the activity based on which marker you clicked. 

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng chennai = new LatLng(12.9671, 80.2593);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(chennai).title("Chennai"));

        LatLng perungudi = new LatLng(12.97, 80.25);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(perungudi).title("Perungudi"));

        LatLng pallikarnai = new LatLng(12.9377, 80.2154);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pallikarnai).title("Pallikarnai"));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(chennai,12));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                if (marker.getTitle().equals("Chennai")){
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Clicked"+marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: I think it is a better idea to recognise the marker from its `tag` instead of the title. It can be set like `marker.setTag(theID);`